# What does ax=ax do while creating a plot in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axes

I have a DataFrame of Heart Disease patients, which has over 300 values. What I have done initially is filter the patients aging over 50. Now I am trying to plot that DF, but running on Google, I found this piece of code that helped me plotting it.

But I am not able to understand the concept of ax = ax here:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
over_50.plot(x="age",
             y="chol",
             c="target",
             kind="scatter",
 --------->  ax=ax);  <---------
```

I want to learn the concept behind this little piece of code here. What is it doing at its core?

Comment: As you mentioned `over_50` is a pandas dataframe. `over_50.plot(...,ax=ax)` dictates that `plt` draws the plots into `ax`, which is an axis instance. This is used when you have several active axis instances.

Answer (score 1):

In this case (a **single** *axes* plot) you can do without this parameter.

But there are more complex cases, when you create subplots with
**a number** of *axes* objects (a *grid*).

In this case *ax* (the second result from *plt.subplots()*) is an **array**
of *axes* objects.

Then, creating each plot, you should specify in which *axes* this plot
is to be created.

See e.g. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html
and find title *Stacking subplots in one direction*.

It contains such example:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
axs[0].plot(x, y)
axs[1].plot(x, -y)
```

Here:

- there is created a figure composed of 2 columns,
- in the first *axes* there is created one line plot, and in the second - another plot.

Alternative form of how to specify *axes* object in which particular plot
is to be created is just *ax* parameter, like in our code,
where you can pass one of *axes* objects from the current figure.

Comment: yes, I did try to create a plot without using this parameter. But it then gives me two plots, one empty and the other one with data plotted on it.